# Pass error data from one component to another

Tags: angular

I have 2 child components and I want to pass the error data from the one child component which does a service call to the other child component. The restriction is that I can't use `router` in this case.

Child 1

```
this.avafService.SubmitAVAFLoanAdjustment(this.submitAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest).subscribe((resp)=>{
   //success
}, error => {
      console.log(error);
     //set error value to model
})
```

Child 2

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  //get error here
  //import model in Child 2 component and get model data
}
```

Service

Model

```
export interface ErrorDetail {
  isError: boolean
  statusNumber: number
  statusHeaderCode: string
  errorDescription: string
  errorDescriptionKey: string
  errorDescriptionIcon: string
  errorList: ResultMessage[]
}
```

What else can I do to pass the data? I have a service and model file that I am trying to use but am not sure what to do next. I added comments of what I am trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I used to achieve thesame result
First create services myservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorRportService {
  errorReport = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }
}
```

From you child1

```
constructor(private errorReport:ErrorRportService) { }
this.avafService.SubmitAVAFLoanAdjustment(this.submitAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest).subscribe((resp)=>{
   //success
}, error => {
      console.log(error);
this.errorReport.next(error);
     //set error value to model
})
```

Then subscribe it in your child 2

```
constructor(private errorReport:ErrorRportService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
  //get error here
  //import model in Child 2 component and get model data
this.errorReport.errorReport.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can do this by using a Subject that is basically a observable:

**In Service File**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    
    errorSubject = new Subject<any>();  // any can be replaced by the error resp JSON Type
```

**In Child component 1 :**

```
import {ServiceFileClassName} from './path';
.
.
.
constructor(private service: ServiceFileClassName){} 
this.avafService.SubmitAVAFLoanAdjustment(this.submitAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest).subscribe((resp)=>{
       //success
    }, error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.service.errorSubject.next(error) // pass the error response in the subject
    })
```

**In Child Component 2:**

```
 import {Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import {ServiceFileClassName} from './path';
        .
        .
        .
        constructor(private service: ServiceFileClassName){}
        subs:Subscription;
        this.subs= this.service.errorSubject.subscribe((resp=>{
        //use the error response that you get
        })
        .
        .
        .
        ngOnDestroy(){
          this.subs.unsubscribe()
        }
```

Also, implement onDestroy in the child2 component and unsubscribe to the subject's subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an Event Emitter or a better solution would be create an Observable inside the service & let the service trigger the error instead of the component & then subscribe inside the components to it.

Comment: I am not sure how to create the service code

Comment: Simple solution would be to use event emmiter if you are not familiar with services you can watch some videos about how to implement `@Output` & `@Input` decorator & then pass data between components.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try the following approach:

In the `Child2` component typescript, you have to create a method to receive the value of the `error` variable like this:

```
export class Child2Component {

constructor() { }

error:string;

receiveStringValue($event) {
  this.error= $event
 }
}
```

In the `Child2` component html put the following:

```
<app-child1 (stringValueEvent)="receiveStringValue($event)"></app-child1>
<h1>{{error}}<h1>
```

In the `Child1` component typescript (app-child1 selector), you should declare a stringValueEvent variable with the `@Output()` decorator and set it equal to a new event emitter.

```
export class Child1Component {

  error:string = "This is a demo error message";

  @Output() stringValueEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stringValueEvent.emit(this.error)
  }
}
```